# How do I remove the extra height in my <li>?

Tags: css, hover

I'm not sure how to ask this clearly, so I will just post the code:

```css
body {
  background-color: #232026;
  background-image: url('galaxy16cropped.jpg');
  background-position: center top;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-size: 2000px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  font-family: 'Lato', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
a:hover:not(.nav) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
div.nav {
  background-color: #232026;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 6px 0px 6px 0px;
  height: 40px;
}
.nav li {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0px;
}
li.current {
  background-color: #424242;
}
.nav li.current:hover {
  background-color: #424242;
}
.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #737373;
}
.nav a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  width: 140px;
}
.nav p {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 140px;
}
.content p {
  text-align: justify;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  max-width: 400px;
}
.container p {
  text-align: justify;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
div.bar {
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DBDBDB;
  border-top: 1px solid #DBDBDB;
  background-color: #424242;
  opacity: 0.8;
  text-align: center;
}
ul {
  text-align: justify;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.body li {
  font-size: 80%;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}
.body li:before {
  content: "\25B7";
  padding-right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <img src="logotranspwhite.png" height="40px" style="float:left; margin-right:10px; margin-left:15px; border: none;">
  <ul>
    <li class="current">
      <p>Home</p>
    </li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="null">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You can see that the hover background is taller than the `.current` background. This is solved by removing the `a:hover:not(.nav)` near the top of the css. I added the not(.nav) to try to fix this, but it didn't help. I'd like to keep the `a:hover` for the rest of the page, but I can't even out my menu backgrounds.

I'm very confused by this! Thanks for your help!

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/ (coupled with Sean's answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add layout to your `.nav li` selector.

```
.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

or you can float it:

```
.nav li {
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, at one point it was `inline block`, I don't know when that got changed. The `a:hover` is still overriding the color of the `.nav li:hover` though, even if I use
    .nav li:hover {
        background-color:#E36052 !important;
    }

Comment: Ok, adding `.nav a:hover {
 background-color:#E36052;` fixed it.